# Problems using XftColorAllocValue in X11 package Xft (associated with XRender, too)

Tags: x11, antialiasing, color-mapping, color-palette, argb

I'm trying to use the trio of X11 package **Xft**, **FontConfig**, and **XRender**. In particular, I'm trying to use the function `XftColorAllocValue`.

From the single line of documentation, and from successfully using `XftColorAllocName`, I infer that the last two values passed to it are an `XRenderColor`, specifying the desired values, and an `XftColor`, returning the color values allocated as well as the associated pixel in that `struct`.

No matter what values I give for `ARGB` values in `XRenderColor`, the boolean returned by the call is always 1, and the `XftColor` values (including those in the embedded `XRenderColor`) all set to `0` - that is, it fails, but does set the returned structure values, but to `0`.

Comment: It seems (undocumented) that returning '1' is in the case meant to indicate success. Also, elsewhere I found that setting Xresource values may help, and I think they do:

Comment: Also, elsewhere I found that setting Xresource values may help, and I think they do:  'Xft.antialias:  1'  
'Xft.dpi:    96'  
'Xft.hinting:    1'  
'Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight'  
'Xft.lcdfilter:  lcddefault'  
'Xft.rgba:   rgb'  
Emacs.font: Liberation Mono-12'